# How to use CSS Global Variables?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

first of all thank you so much for your time.

My doubt is simple, but i couldn't find a way to get it working.

So... basically i have a '/pages/_app.js' file:

```
import '../public/styles/global.css';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

A global css file '/public/styles/global.css':

```
:root {
  --bg-color: #000;
}
```

A css module file '/public/styles/header.module.css':

```
.header {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

And finally a home page '/pages/index.js'that uses the css class:

```
import React from 'react';
import headerStyle from '../public/styles/header.module.css';

export default function Home() {
  return <div className={headerStyle.header}>Test</div>;
}
```

I don't get an error but i didn't manage to refer to the global variables inside the css modules.
Can you guys help me with what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `pages/` directory exists under `src/` then the path to the `<Home>` component should be `/src/pages/` and the import for the `headerStyle` should be the following:

```
import headerStyle from "../../public/styles/header.module.css";
```

You just need to go up one more directory.

```
/*
 *  @filename /src/pages/index.jsx
 */
import React from "react";
import headerStyle from "../../public/styles/header.module.css";

const Home = () => {
  return <div className={headerStyle.header}>Test</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-root-styles-qm71h?file=/src/index.jsx) snippet to demonstrate.